# Take a picture from terminal

Tags: command-line, webcam

I want to be able to take a picture using the webcam from the terminal. This image then will be saved to a file. How can this be done?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you're looking for something automated `webcam` is pretty decent. It has lots of lovely options for pushing the photos over the Internet.

If you want something more manual, and we're talking about a camera supported by V4L/UVC (most of them) you can use `streamer` to capture a frame from the device:

```
streamer -f jpeg -o image.jpeg
```

Comment: Thanks Oli. Did not know a webcam program called WEBCAM (The irony...) existed. And yes the webcam is in the V4L supported list.

Comment: If you get something like "`neither audio nor video format specified/found`" with the command `streamer -f jpeg -o image.jpeg`, try just `streamer -o image.jpeg`.

Answer (score 72):

There is another application which can be used to capture the images from the webcam named as 
 **Fswebcam**. you can install that with

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```

you can have a sample shot with the following command.

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 -D 1 web-cam-shot.jpg
```

In the above code syntax , `-r` stands for Image resolution , `--jpeg` stand for format type of the image & `85` for its quality standard, `-D` stands for delay set before capture.

Now your image finally saved with web-cam-shot.jpg name.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my case, my test machine, I had to skip frames to get the picture right. If I take the first frames the picture are very dark, because the camera wasn't ready yet.

`fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 100 -D 3 -S 13 fswebcam.jpg`

Comment: @tenshimsm I spent 10 mins figuring out what was wrong with my fswebcam and then removed the package. Installed it again just to try your approach, 30 frames worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: With my 5.99€ bleeding edge Sodial webcam, `avconv` works better.

Comment: what I've wound helpful is: v4lctl bright 50% # apt-get install xawtv

Comment: `--no-banner ` (removes the bottom banner with time stamp)

Answer (score 41):

Using `avconv` or `ffmpeg`, you can capture a frame from your device as well. For example:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -ss 0:0:2 -frames 1 /tmp/out.jpg
```

or

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -ss 0:0:2 -frames 1 /tmp/out.jpg
```

This will open `/dev/video0` as a `video4linux2` compatible device, set up resolution to `640x480`, stream for 2 seconds (`00:00:02` or simply `2`), then capture `one` single frame, saving it to `/tmp/out.jpg`.

Check if your device is `/dev/video0`, as it can be different for you.

The available resolutions depend on your webcam. Mine goes up to 640x480 and I checked it with a tool called `qv4l2`, which is used to configure a video4linux2 device.

The `-ss` parameter is used to allow the device to start up correctly. Here in my tests, there is a fade-in effect while the camera is being turned on, so, if I just omit `-ss 2`, the captured frame will be very dark.

Comment: I preferred this solution as I'd already installed avconv. Also, the output of avconv also gives hints to the maximum resolution, as the v4l driver shows if it has to fall back onto a lower specification.

Comment: I use this because FFMpeg gave me better quality than the other options.

Answer (score 11):

You can also try [uvccapture](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/uvccapture.1.html).

```
uvccapture -m
```