# Easiest way to take a continous series of pictures from a webcam

Tags: command-line, webcam

Looking around I found several solutions to take individual pictures ([a few solutions are given here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106770/take-a-picture-from-terminal)) and even a series of pictures (with up to one fps). I want to store the pictures in much lower time steps (5-10 fps would be great) and as these solutions operate like:

turn on camera --> take picture --> turn off camera --> sleep --> turn on camera -->...

I did not find a way to make pictures this fast. Thus I am looking for a (elegant) solution, which does not turn off the camera.

I know of two work-around:

1. open maximized mplayer with webcam stream and make screen shots
2. make snippets of video and convert them back in a series of pictures

but these seem very unreasonable...

Note: I am explicitly looking for a solution that can be operated from the terminal!

Answer (score 2):

`streamer` can still do this:

```
streamer -t99999999999999 -r 10 -o output0000000.jpeg
```

The awkward looking `-t` argument is there to cope with the fact that `streamer` needs to know how long it's going to be recording for. Still, that's several thousand years. Just <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit out when you're done recording.

The `-r` argument sets your framerate.