# Take photo using webcam

Tags: 14.04, drivers, webcam

I would like to take a photo from my webcam. As I moved from Windows to Ubuntu I wonder if there is a built-in way to achieve this or I need special software. If so can you suggest a good one?

Comment: from terminal http://askubuntu.com/questions/106770/take-a-picture-from-terminal

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There's an application called *cheese* which can do this. IIRC it's installed by default. If not, you can install it manually using the software center or by typing `sudo apt-get install cheese` into a terminal window.

Comment: Seems to be not installed by default in Lubuntu.

Answer (score 34):

I would suggest you use Cheese. It is a webcam program for Ubuntu that supports almost any webcam.

You can install it by running the following command in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

After that, it will display in your installed programs menus.